# Windows application 3 tier C# in SQL server for Billing System

Tags: c#

I am new to `3 Tier Architecture` in `C# Windows Application` in `SQL Server` .
  I want to build a project in this area to create a Billing System Software ( I want to insert delete update and select the records from UI part and store in database).  I have already knowledge in SQL Database.  I know about C# but I am very beginner in 3 tier architecture concept.  Can anyone help in this regard.

Comment: Try to google it first.

Comment: Please provide some more details/code in which you got stucked, show some efforts and than we can help to get it resolved. Question you are asking is very broad level.

Comment: this should not be a question, try to google, (Creating application in 3tier architechture c#)                                                                                                            refer articles like this-> http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/85482/Create-a-Business-Logic-Layer-Data-Access-Layer-cl

Answer (score 0):

create a class library for your data layer and another one for your business layer
add reference of your data layer to your  business layer.
and add reference of your  business layer to your UI layer (windows application)

create another class library for your common layer if you need it and add reference it to all your layars